# Form Submittion and flow up with NodeJS

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, web-crawler, form-submit

I prefer using NodeJS, to acheive the follow flow,
Navigate to a site, find a form, set values, submit form, get the result of submittion (usually redirect), find hrefs there, and navigate to them.

which package is the best documented and supports those?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`PhantomJS` and `CasperJs` are great js tools for web scraping, maybe a little difficult to learn.
`SpookyJS` allows you to run PhantomJS/CasperJS within Nodejs environnement.

Those packages are well documented.
Recently, i discovered an interessting package named `nightmare` that is 'a high-level browser automation library'.

[Here is a link for nightmare](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nightmare)

Comment: PhantomJS has some ports to NodeJS which are great, thanks for the intro to CasperJs, Nightmare is nice - but it's too slow and heavy since it's running a browser and simulating real user - Thanks alot!